# How to do while statement with multiple if condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

start learning python here and want to do some modification through my online courses:

```
while True:
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input()
    character = int(len(name))
    if character < 3 or character > 20:
        print("Name can only less than 3 character and no more than 50 character")
    else:
        print(f"Welcome back, {name}")
        break
```

Basically I want my code to do:

1. Input name
2. If the name is less than 3 character, the error message shows and it gets back to enter the name
3. If the name is more than 50 character, the error message shows and it gets back to enter the name
4. If the name is more than 3 and less than 50, then the welcome back message shows up.

My code do exactly what it says but I wonder if I can get the notification customized through each condition. Any help will be very much appreciated since this is what I can came up browsing through stackoverflow. (or the simplest one that I can understand)

Comment: is the indentation here correct? Please double check.

Comment: what you expected? I can't understand your question is?

Comment: What do exactly you mean "get the notification customized through each condition"? It looks to me like that is already the case.

Answer (score 1):

add and else if: statement like this

```
while True:
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input()
    character = int(len(name))
    if character < 3:
        print("Name can only less than 3 character and no more than 50 character")
    elif character > 50:
        print("Error message")
    else:
        print(f"Welcome back, {name}")
        break
```

Comment: Tried that before and the elif condition got ignored because the first if is already passed. The results go straightforward to welcome back. Any ideas?

Comment: You removed the 'or character > 20' part of the first if statement?

Comment: It should check the first if statement first, is that's false it should go to the first else if statement. If that's false as well it should go to the else statement, which he will always execute if none of the above if/else if's where true.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got confused in the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `elif`

for instace:

```
elif character > 50:
    print("name is {} characters long, please try again".format(character))
```

Comment: The first if condition got accepted and the second elif (character > 50) got ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: not sure how you pasted it in your code, maybe update your question with it if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got confused in the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for the actual number inside the `if`.

```
if character < 3 or character > 50:
    print("Name can only have more than 3 character" if character < 3 else "Name can only have less than 50 character")
```

Or just use general message for both scenarios

```
if character < 3 or character > 50:
    print(f"Name must be between 3 and 50 characters, {character} where inserted")
```

You could also reverse the checks to remove the `else`

```
if 2 < character < 51:
    print(f"Welcome back, {name}")
    break
print(f"Name must be between 3 and 50 characters, {character} where inserted")
```